# How to send output to browser before C# azure function finishes?

Tags: c#, http, azure-functions

I want to develop an azure function that performs some tasks that take some seconds and it will be triggered manually from a browser. Is there a possibility to already provide some output to the browser before everything is finished?

For example something like:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class HttpTriggerCSharp1
    {
        [FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            SendPartialResponse("starting task 1"); // <- how to implement this?

            DoSomethingThatTakesSomeTime();

            SendPartialResponse("starting task 2"); // <- how to implement this?
         
            DoSomethingElseThatTakesSomeTime();

            return new OkObjectResult("finished"); // <- no problem if return code has to be sent earlier
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean of `provide some output before everything is finished` ? Do you mean output something in the browser page ? Or output something in logs ?

Comment: Output something in the browser page

Comment: That's exactly the opposite way that Azure Functions are intended to be used.

Comment: @IanKemp And what IS the correct azure product for achieving the same result?

Comment: It sounds like you want to send the progress of the Azure Function back to the caller? I dig some digging around and found this, which might give you an idea? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ec786bd1-eace-494d-8fa0-480c5d3f917e/how-to-report-progress-to-clients?forum=AzureFunctions    or this   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-custom-orchestration-status?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 1):

In order to actively push messages back to the web browser, you will have to use full-duplex messaging. One approach would be to implement your function using tech like SignalR.

Following docs and samples will allow you to get started:

A walk-through from MS docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-csharp

Sample on GitHub:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/signalr-service-quickstart-serverless-chat

Comment: That is probably the correct solution for a full fledged web application, but my expectation would be that there is something much more simple (i.e. using HTTP chunked transfer encoding or something similar).